# Neo4j type mismatch

Tags: java, eclipse, jdbc, neo4j

I am trying to write a JDBC code in eclipse that connects to neo4j. I can get it to connect to the database, but I am having troubles getting the queries to run. I have the Neo4J driver jar imported as well as most of the driver imports needed. This being said, I am still getting errors in two places:

```
PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(cypher);
```

gives me the error:

Multiple markers at this line

```
- The method prepareStatement(String) is undefined for the type Connection

- Type mismatch: cannot convert from java.sql.PreparedStatement to org.neo4j.jdbc.PreparedStatement
```

I am confused why java.sql is included because I don't have it imported into this class.

My other error is at line:

Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:neo4j:bolt://localhost", "", "");

The error I get here is: DriverManager cannot be resolved.

My code (unfinished) is below. My question is, what I should do to help resolve these errors.

```
private static void runCypher(Connection conn, String cypher) {
    PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(cypher);


}

public static void main (String[] args) {
    try {   
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:neo4j:bolt://localhost", "", "");

        String cypher = "";
        String option = "";
        String instr = "Enter a: Show distinct sids and snames of suppliers who supply a red part or a green part." + "\n"
                + "Enter b: Show distinct sids and snames of suppliers who supply a red part and a green part."
                + "\n" + "Enter c: Insert a new supplier." + "\n"
                + "Enter d:  Quit Program.";

    while (true) {
        option = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(instr);
        if (option.equals("a")) {
            cypher = "match (s:Suppliers)-[:supplies]->(p:Parts) where p.color = ‘red’ or p.color = ‘green’ return distinct s.sid, s.sname;";
            runCypher(conn, cypher);
        } else if (option.equalsIgnoreCase("b")) {
            cypher = "match (p1:Parts)<-[:supplies]-(s:Suppliers)-[:supplies]->(p2:Parts) where p1.color = ‘red’ and p2.color = ‘green’ return distinct s.sid, s.sname;";
            runCypher(conn, cypher);
        } else if (option.equals("c")) {
            cypher = "match (p:Parts)<-[sup:supplies]-(s:Suppliers) return p.pid, p.pname, max(toInteger(sup.cost)) order by p.pid;";
            runCypher(conn, cypher);
        } else {
            break;
        }


    }}catch(Exception e ) {
        System.out.println("Program terminates due to errors");
        e.printStackTrace(); // for debugging
    }
}
```

My imports:

```
import org.neo4j.driver.internal.spi.Connection;
import org.neo4j.driver.v1.StatementResult;
import org.neo4j.jdbc.PreparedStatement;
import org.neo4j.jdbc.ResultSet;
import org.neo4j.jdbc.ResultSetMetaData;
```

Comment: I believe your problem is related to the imports... post the relevant ones (DriverManager, Connection, ...) - please **edit the question** to add them

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger I have editted the question

Comment: `java.sql.DriverManager` is missing; try using the `java.sql` classes instead of the `neo4j` ones, e.g., `import java.sql.Connection`, `import java.sqlPreparedStatement`, ...

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger I have to connect to a neo4j database though

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger can I use the sql driver for that

Comment: normally you never have to use the drivers classes, these are automatically used in the background. Just try it

Comment: "can I use the sql driver"  there is no such driver, just an **Interface**. Each database has its own driver, that must implement the `java.sql.Driver` **Interface**. Most implement SQL, but I do not believe Neo4J does support SQL. (a bit confusing that jdbc package is *incorrectly* named `java.sql`)

Answer (score 1):

The error Message `DriverManager cannot be resolved` means that the compiler does not know about that class/field/... so it probably is missing the corresponding import:

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
```

The error `The method prepareStatement(String) is undefined for the type Connection` means that this method was not found, because you are importing, and so using, the wrong `Connection` class. I cannot remember ever using the classes from the driver JAR, despite the Driver itself that needed to be loaded (some time ago...). The correct classes are used be Java based on the URL given to the `DriverManager`. You only have to use the classes from the `java.sql` package....

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
...
```

Here a very simple example:

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

public class Neo4j {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:neo4j:bolt://localhost", "neo4j", "test123")) {
            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("MATCH (a:Aplz) RETURN *");
            ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery();
            while (rset.next()) {
                System.out.println(rset.getObject(1));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Actually, with never Java, you only need the `DriverManager`, the compiler does a good job on that:

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class Neo4j {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try (var conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:neo4j:bolt://localhost", "neo4j", "test123")) {
            var stmt = conn.prepareStatement("MATCH (a:Aplz) RETURN *");
            var rset = stmt.executeQuery();
            while (rset.next()) {
                System.out.println(rset.getObject(1));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I dont understand why i would use java.sql when I am accessing Neo4j

Comment: that is the way that drivers work. The Neo4J driver registers to the DriverManager. When the DriverManager gets the url `"jdbc:neo4j..."` it will do his magic and find a class that implements `java.sql.Connection` (actually an instance that returns such a instance). And you just have to work with the Interface (same as with List and ArrayList) - that is the way it is intended, so you can easily change the database (in theory)

Comment: another advantage, you do not need the driver to compile your application - the application is not dependent from the driver itself (not considering that the queries can be database specific - specially for Neo4J)